# What difference between binding and variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, binding

In my studying I see which a variable make a connection between a value and a name but the binding have the same function, when to use a and other?

Binding and Variable?

Comment: Could you share the source where **binding** is described?

Comment: Yeah, book Eloquent JavaScript 3° edition

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When running your program, a Javascript engine keeps track of all used names (identifiers) in so-called "Environment Records". Each scope (an `{...}` block) and each function has its own ER.

ER's are similar to normal javascript objects, they have keys (=identifiers), values and prototypes (parent ER's). On the top level there is the Global ER, which contains built-in names like `Array` or `undefined`.

Now, each entry (key-value pair) in an ER is called a "binding". Some of these bindings are "variables", but some are not. In the example above, `Array` is hardly a variable.

Comment: Oh my god, this helped me quite! Thanks